# How can I assign data from API to a global variable in Android?

Tags: android, api, asynchronous, kotlin, global

var datasFromApi: ArrayList = arrayListOf()

btnNextCharacter.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

```
        if(checkForInternetConnection()) {

            try {
                val innerClassObject = DownloadingCharacterTask()
                innerClassObject.execute()

            }catch (e: Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }    
        }
}
```

inner class DownloadingCharacterTask : AsyncTask>() {

```
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): List<Characters>? {

        var parseCharacter = ParseCharacterUtility()
        return parseCharacter.parseCharacterObjectFromJSONData()
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: List<Characters>?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

        var numberOfCharacters = result?.size ?: 0
        var index: Int = 0

        while (index < result!!.size) {
            datasFromApi[index].name = result[index].name
            datasFromApi[index].height = result[index].height
            datasFromApi[index].mass = result[index].mass
            datasFromApi[index].gender = result[index].gender
            datasFromApi[index].birthYear = result[index].birthYear
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome :) Please use the code ({ }) button to make your code readable and some text explanation to your question.

Comment: First question I will be better next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
datasFromApi = innerClassObject.execute().get();
```

It can get a return value, but blocks the UIThread for that time.
That is, when get() is used, it is synchronous rather than asynchronous while getting the return value.
It's okay to use get() if there's no UI-related processing.

Comment: There was a UI Thread but separated them. Then It worked mate! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTasks` uses 3 type parameters namely

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

}
```

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#asynctasks-generic-types):

> 1. **Params**, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
> 2. **Progress**, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
> 3. **Result**, the type of the result of the background computation.

You can use the **Result** type to return some value and store it in some global variable.

Having said that, you should reconsider the use of `AsyncTask` (its a horrid thing from the past) and Android is about to ditch this monster soon. 
Hope that helps.